# Im unable to calculate the length of the passed array using pointers but why?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I want to calculate the length of an array inside a function, to use it for iteration. But the normal pointer method to calculate the array isnt working. Why? What changes can i make to my code to make it work? Im aware there are much better ways to go about getting the length, or to print the array, but what is fundamentally wrong in this method?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print(int ar[]){
    int len = *(&ar + 1) - ar;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        cout << ar[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main() {
    int aa[] = {2,3,1};
    print(aa);
}
```

Output of the above code is a blank line (only `endl` is being print)

When I write `cout << len;` inside the function, the output turns out to be `-4292483`, which seems like a random number.

Comment: In a function parameter list, arrays are automatically replaced with pointers. `int arr[]` there means `int *arr`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat oh okay, but then how do i use that to calculate the length? and the pointer is a pointer to the array or the first element of the array?

Comment: Why not just use `std::array`?

Comment: In the so called C-style arrays, the pointer to the array is the pointer to the first element of that array.

Comment: The info about the array size is irrevokably gone once the the array decays. You could of course make the function a pointer receiving a fixed-sized array reference: `template<size_t N> void print(int (&ar)[N]) { for (size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i) ... }`

Comment: The best change to your code is to use std::array<> or std::vector<> and avoid c-style arrays. If you are forced to use them you either have to use a template like the above comment from @fabian or pass the size as a parameter

Comment: *"then how do i use that to calculate the length?"* You pass it as a separate parameter. *"the pointer is a pointer to the array or the first element of the array"* The two have the same numerical value, but different types. Pointer to first element is `int *` (this is what you have), and pointer to whole array is `int (*)[N]`.

Comment: @fabian ahh okay okay, thank you, size simply cant be gotten. Ill check out to use templates

Comment: @HolyBlackCat wait, isnt a pointer to the whole array `int **` (thats the error im getting for some random variations in my code); what exactly is `int(*) [N]` ?

Comment: `int **` is a pointer to pointer, not pointer to array. `int (*)[N]` is a "pointer to array of size N of int". A variable of this type would be declared like this: `int (*ptr)[N] = ...;`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat okay, now after i change my parameters of the `print` function as `void print(int (*ar)[]){ ... }`, i cant use the pointer to the array because size is unspecified, is it possible to use it as such or in another way without specifying the size?

Comment: No, you have to pass the size separately, or make the function a template as suggested above.